# Run Python code on Google Form submission or Google Sheet update

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-forms

I've created a Google Form. When somebody fills it out and submits, I would like to run some Python code using the submission answers.

My current system is having a Google Sheet tied to the Google Form, which constantly updates with new answers. Then, I have an infinite loop running in Python on my PC that grabs the sheet contents in a database and checks if they have change. If they have, run code with the new entry.

This process requires me to have an infinite loop running constantly on my PC, which isn't great.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Just throwing some ideas at you so don't quote me but; with the google sheet/form if there is a "submit" action, can you control what happens once that event is triggered? If so you might be able to use AWS Lambda (event driven code execution).
If you need an infinite loop, just not on your pc, you may have to start looking into getting a little cloud server set up. I've only done this with AWS EC2 so that would be my recommendation, but I'm by no means an expert...

Comment: Do you know if EC2 has a free tier like lambda?

Comment: I don't off the top of my head sorry. There may be some other service that is better suited to your use case, EC2 is simply what I have experience in which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: I might consider a webapp to give your python code and end point to access to a queue of the latest submissions that you haven't already looked at.  And let google apps script maintain the process of collecting all of the new submissions from an on'form submit trigger which has an event object that provides all of the submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

#### This can be easily solved by making use of Cloud Functions!

Google Cloud Functions is a serverless environment for building and connecting cloud services and it is used to create single purpose functions that respond to events without a server or a runtime. They are triggered when an event being watched is fired.

Therefore, you should start by creating a Cloud Function in the Google Cloud Platform, configure it to your needs and input your Python code into the editor, along with the dependencies:

[image: cloud function]

Afterwards, you can easily trigger this function from Apps Script, by using the following function (assuming that `triggerCloudFunction` is the function that gets run whenever a form submission is sent):

```
function triggerCloudFunction() {
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    'CLOUD_FUNCTION_TRIGGER_URL',
    {
      method: 'GET',
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()}`
      }
    }
  )
  console.log(response.getContentText())
}
```

In order to make this work appropriately, you will also have to include the `openid` scope in the `appsscript.json` manifest file.

#### Reference

- [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview).